# awk print words between variable space delimiters as array

Tags: arrays, awk

Supposing Ive a row like this:

```
LOCUS       NG_052676              31180 bp    DNA     linear   PRI 08-AUG-2017
```

Which is being selected by   `match($0, /LOCUS\s*([^\n]*)/, o)`

And printed by `print o[1]`

But this selects/prints the entire row because of the white space:

```
NG_052676              31180 bp    DNA     linear   PRI 08-AUG-2017
```

How can I capture the first two strings as an array, o, such that: o[1] = NG_052676 and o[2] = 31180 ?

*NB I don't want to change the FS variable as that is being used for something else*

*NB2 This is the entire awk function I am using:*

```
BEGIN{RS="//";FS=OFS="|"}
{
  match($0, /LOCUS\s*([^\n]*)/, o)
  match($0, /\(([^)]+)\)/, a)
  match($0, /\/gene="([^"]+)"/, b)
  match($0, /\/product="([^"]+)"/, c)
  match($0, /\/chromosome="([^"]+)"/, d)
  match($0, /\/map="([^"]+)"/, e)
  match($0, /Summary:\s([^\[]+)/, f)

  print o[1] " ", a[1] " ",b[1] " ", gensub(/\s\s+/, " ", "g1", c[1]) " ", 
  d[1] " ", e[1] " ",
    gensub(/\s\s+/, " ", "g2", f[1])
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you think `"g1"` and `"g2"` might mean as gensub() args but gawk will just treat them both as `"g"`. That arg is either a number for the regexp occurrence you want to match or `"g"` to match all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. When I cloned the first gensub statement I wanted to make sure the variable g wouldn't conflict with the previous statement (very new to awk)

Comment: You're welcome. You really should post a new question though so we could help steer you down the right path. For example, all of those match lines like `match($0, /\/gene="([^"]+)"/, b)` should probably be consolidated into a single line like `match($0, /\/([[:alpha:]]+)="([^"]+)"/, b) { f[b[1]]=b[2] }` and you could then later refer to the values by their names, e.g. `print f["gene"], f["map"]`. It's also extremely unlikely that `FS="|"` is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk (which you're already using) for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0, /LOCUS\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/, o) { print o[1], o[2] }' file
NG_052676 31180
```

Comment: You're welcome. Your approach in the rest of your script is really odd though - usually when you have name->value mappings it's best to simply create an array that stores those mappings. Creating a bunch of separate arrays for each "name" to hold its value is very cumbersome. If you post a new question with concise, testable sample input and expected output I'm sure someone will be able to help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Since by default awk is using white space as FS , why not to consider the simpliest awk format?

```
$ f1="LOCUS       NG_052676              31180 bp    DNA     linear   PRI 08-AUG-2017"
$ awk '{o[1]=$2;o[2]=$3}{print o[1],o[2]}' <(echo "$f1")
NG_052676 31180
```

You can still combine it with your regex:

```
$ awk '/LOCUS/{o[1]=$2;o[2]=$3;print o[1],o[2]}' <(echo "$f1")
```

Comment: Thank you George, how would you combine it with the match function?

Comment: @hb Why you need to combine with match since can be done without it?

Comment: Because its part of a more complex function